# Flask-RestFul: Request works well while using Postman. But returns 500 response when making request from android

Tags: python, json, flask, httprequest, flask-restful

I am using flask-restful's request parser to parse arguments in a JSON sent via a POST request.

The request works well while using Postman tool. But returns 500 response when making request from android.

My resource class is:

```
class QuestionIgnore(restful.Resource):

    @login_required
    def post(self):
        q_ignore_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        q_ignore_parser.add_argument('question_id', type=str, location='json', required=True)

        print request.json

        args = q_ignore_parser.parse_args()
        #do something with the database
        return {'question_id':args['question_id']}
```

This below should be perfectly valid request for this resource:

```
Content-Length: 48
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H)
Connection: close
Host: myhost.com
X-Forward-For: 111.111.111.111
X-Deviceid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"question_id":"somerandomstring123456789"}
```

The request works perfectly when using postman to test the API, but when sending request from within the android application the server returns a 500 response code. I get the following traceback when this request is sent:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 257, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 257, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 397, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 487, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 764, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/MY_PROJECT/api/resources.py", line 617, in post
    args = q_ignore_parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/reqparse.py", line 212, in parse_args
    namespace[arg.dest or arg.name] = arg.parse(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/reqparse.py", line 131, in parse
    values = [source.get(name)]
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I first thought it was due to malformed JSON, but the JSON being sent by android is perfect, same as the postman request. The content type header is also intact. In fact if the request is malformed, server should return a 400 response not 500.

Any Idea what might be causing this?

Comment: `source` in exception should be equal to `request.json` (`MultiDict`). For me it work fine. Try debug.

Comment: i printed type(source) from reqparse.py. All other requests with json payload and similar request parsers print werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict. whereas this one print unicode.

Still stuck.